# Add headers HttpRequest in NestJS

Tags: javascript, angular, httprequest, nestjs

I'm trying to make a Http request in NestJS

As it's inspired from angular I jave append my Headers

```
import { Injectable, HttpService} from '@nestjs/common';
...
const headersRequest = new Headers();
headersRequest.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headersRequest.append('Authorization', `Basic ${encodeToken}`);
```

Then call the api

```
const result = await this.httpService.post(apiUrl, newDevice, { headers: headersRequest });
```

I get an error

```
ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
```

And when I ass `Headers` to import
I get this message waring in VScode

```
Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

NestJS uses [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) under the hood to make http requests, take a look at its documentation for request configuration:

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Looks like there is no interface for headers, just pass a plain JS dictionary object:

```
const headersRequest = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // afaik this one is not needed
    'Authorization': `Basic ${encodeToken}`,
};

const result = await this.httpService.post(apiUrl, newDevice, { headers: headersRequest });
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option (since nest v5 introduced HttpModule.registerAsync) if your `encodeToken` is pretty static or hardcoded from your config is setting it up in the module level:

```
import { Module, HttpModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '..';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';


@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        baseURL: configService.get('vendors.apiEndpoint'),
        headers: {          
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + configService.get('vendors.encodeToken')
        },
        timeout: 7000,
        maxRedirects: 5
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    })
  ],
  // ... other module stuff
})

export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: How to call the API in service because the Header authorization is added here if call it shows the token is missing.

Answer (score 4):

I think this method false 
in for read   headers parameter just   req.headers
example

```
 @Get()
    findHeaderexample(@Res() res,@Req req) {
        return req.headers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riadh but It's not exactly what I would make, I would set header to make a httpRequest inside a controller ( inside a service exactely ) and not get req headers

Comment: Possible explain   your  idea

Answer (score 4):

You also can change it with axios interceptor:

```
this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Basic ${encodeToken}`;
      return config;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a custom header, you can use `@ApiHeader()`

```
@ApiHeader({
  name: 'api-key',
  description: 'api-key',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use withCredentials option as below:

```
export const HttpMessagingProvider = HttpModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    baseURL: configService.get('vendors.apiEndpoint'),
    timeout: 5000,
    maxRedirects: 5,
    withCredentials: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService]
});
```