# Authorization header missing in POST call done via NESTJS application

Tags: .net-core, axios, nestjs

The scenario is that I am trying to hit an API which is in .NET-Core application from my NESTJS application and the while doing that the **Authorization** header is missing in the .Net-Core side. Rest all the headers are getting attached just this **Authorization** header is missing

I am using the **nestjs/axios** library to send the POST call and in the .Net-Core Side I have added all the required headers in CORS policy.

**Problem**:-

In NESTJS, I have a service, let's say, **DemoService**

I am calling an api using nestjs/axios like this:

```
this.httpService.post(url, data, config); // config = {headers: {'Authorization': "bearer", "abc": "abc"}}
```

And in .Net side there is a **middleware** where I am trying to read the Authorization header like this:-

```
var bearer = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

But this bearer is coming as empty.

Need some help on this.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105763/nestjs-passing-authorization-header-to-httpservice
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972616/add-headers-httprequest-in-nestjs

Comment: @jishansiddique Thanks for quick response. I tried the answer which you sent. But still the same issue.